# which one is better....to use styles so that images gets converted runtime OR using mini-magick on after create callback method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

i am using `paperclip` with `amazon s3` to **upload multiple images(max 4) at a time**.i am using styles option to convert images to different dimensions.Now i feel that uploading 4 images takes a bit time which also includes converting them to different sizes which overall affects the performance and take time.I decided to use delayed_paperclip and put those styling in the background using `process_in_background :images` 
but still i was wondering as ***what if i dont use `delayed_paperclip` and use `mini_magick` to convert the images in after_create callback rather than using a new gem.what is the perfect option for this scenario if i want to go ahead????***

Comment: There's never a "perfect option": you have a triangle of speed, solidity and development time with most things.  How long does it take to do all the necessary processing synchronously with mini_magick?  If it takes eg 1 second i'd be tempted to do it synchronously.

Comment: Well, development time and solidity don't really come into it here. All of the development time has been put in for you (`delayed_paperclip`), and it's a reliable solution, much more reliable than an `after_create` block which will not manage failed tasks. I say continue to use `delayed_paperclip`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

even iam using delayed_paperclip..and its one of the best things to work when background jobs are concerned....although i dont know whats the difference between using callback and how it can give more advantage than delayed_paperclip but i believe the gem is made ot that purpose only so that we dont need to write extra code to hande video/image provessing